# Trying to get a querystring variable with an ashx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ashx

I have been trying to sort this out all day with lots of Googling but with little effect so thanks in advance if you read and are able to help.

I have a simple page which allows a user to select files and upload to an Amazon bucket, the first page looks like this:

```
var checkError = false;
$(window).load(
    function () {
        $("#<%=FileImages.ClientID %>").fileUpload({
            'fileSizeLimit': '100MB',
            'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Upload Files',
            'script': 'UploadVB.ashx?gid=56',
            'folder': 'uploads',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true,
            'onAllComplete': function (uploads) {
                if (!checkError) {
                    location.href = "finished";
                }
            },
            'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                if (200 != parseInt(response)) {
                    checkError = true;
                    $('#FileImages' + ID).addClass('uploadifyError');
                    $('#FileImages' + ID + ' .percentage').text(' - ' + response);

                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

);

Note the `gid=56`. It then sends the files over to `UploadVB.ashx` and this looks like this:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim awsRegion As Amazon.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1
    Dim client As New AmazonS3Client(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AWSAccessKey").ToString(), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AWSSecretKey").ToString(), awsRegion)
    Dim fileID As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
    Dim postedFile As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files("Filedata")

    Dim galleryid = context.Request.QueryString("gid")

    Try
        Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)
'### I WANT TO SUBMIT THE FILENAME AND ID INTO A TABLE HERE ######
    AddPortfolioPhoto(filename, Convert.ToInt16(galleryid))
    '#################################################################
        Dim S3_KEY As [String] = filename.Replace(" ", "")
        Dim request As New PutObjectRequest()
        With request
            .BucketName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AWSBucketName").ToString()
            .Key = S3_KEY
            .InputStream = postedFile.InputStream
        End With

        client.PutObject(request)
        context.Response.Write("200")
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200
    Catch ex As Exception
        context.Response.Write("AWS ERROR :: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property
```

Every time I run this above it just doesn't do anything, If I remove this line:

```
AddPortfolioPhoto(filename, Convert.ToInt16(galleryid))
```

it works great but it is crucial I get this inserted into the database someway and I just can't seem to be able to grab the gid value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Public Shared Sub AddPortfolioPhoto(ByVal fn As String, gid As Integer)

    Dim Writer As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Writer.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Writer.CommandText = "BCMS_AddGalleryPhoto"
    Writer.Connection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sqlstr"))
    Writer.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgstr", Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null).Value = fn
    Writer.Parameters.AddWithValue("@galleryid", Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null).Value = gid
    Writer.Parameters.AddWithValue("@so", Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null).Value = 0
    Writer.Parameters.AddWithValue("@featured", Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null).Value = 0
    Writer.Prepare()
    Writer.Connection.Open()
    Writer.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Writer.Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of context.Request.QueryString("gid")?

Comment: It is always an integer, in this case: 56

Comment: The error is coming from AddPortfolio method then. Can you post that code?

Comment: No problem, I have put it above

Comment: That looks like a strange way of using `AddWithValue` - does it work if you use the style `writer.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgstr", fn)` instead? Or, more safely, `writer.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@imgstr", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = fn})`? Also, you should call `writer.Dispose()` at the end of the method.

Comment: Looks like with your help I may have gotten to the bottom of this, the value I was expecting (56) wasn't what I was actually getting, I was actually getting "uploads" in the same variable so sending a string down to this method was never going to work, thanks @matt-dot-net for suggesting and thanks Andrew Morton for the tip on dispose, I will use that rather than close.

Comment: @DaveEvans For your information in the future, if you use the second way I showed of setting a parameter (with the appropriate `.SqlDbType`) it will be more reliable - you would have receive an error message about not being able to set an `SqlDbType.Int` to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like with your help I may have gotten to the bottom of this, the value I was expecting (56) wasn't what I was actually getting, I was actually getting "uploads" in the same variable so sending a string down to this method was never going to work, thanks @matt-dot-net for suggesting and thanks Andrew Morton for the tip on dispose, I will use that rather than close.